# ASP.NET 4.0 Radio button checked changed event fires only once

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two radio buttons both set as async triggers for an update panel and problem is that first time one is clicked the CheckedChanged event fires but then no matter which radio button is clicked the event never fires again.

Markup:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoDeliveryBilling" runat="server" Checked="true" GroupName="DeliveryAddress" Text="Deliver to this address" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdoDelivery_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoDeliveryShipping" runat="server" GroupName="DeliveryAddress" Text="Deliver to a different address" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdoDelivery_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panDeliveryAddress" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    ...delivery details form controls and validators goes here...
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdoDeliveryBilling" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdoDeliveryShipping" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code:

```
protected void rdoDelivery_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...only code that enables/disables the delivery form controls and validators goes here...
}
```

I have set a breakpoint inside rdoDelivery_CheckedChanged and it only hits the first time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the source (in the browser), ASP.NET is only generating a post back function `__doPostBack` for the `RadioButton` controls which can possibly postback.

The first `RadioButton` control cannot postback (because it is already checked), and as such the `__doPostBack` is not generated.

A work around is to add the two `RadioButton` controls to another `UpdatePanel`, setting the `UpdateMode` to Always. This will cause the RadioButtons to be updated (whenever they trigger the other `UpdatePanel`) adding the `__doPostBack` function to the deselected `RadioButton`.

**Example**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelCheckBoxes" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoDeliveryBilling" runat="server" Checked="true" GroupName="DeliveryAddress" Text="Deliver to this address" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdoDelivery_CheckedChanged" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoDeliveryShipping" runat="server" GroupName="DeliveryAddress" Text="Deliver to a different address" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rdoDelivery_CheckedChanged" />            
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve this problem. I may do as you suggested and put the radio buttons in an update panel, or I also found another solution to add the missing onclick: radiobutton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'" & radiobutton.ClientID.Replace("_", "$") & "\',\'\')', 0)")

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. My radio buttons were already inside the update panel. I tried adding an update panel to the individual radio buttons (they were in different places on the page), but couldn't get it to work. But at least I know what the issue is now. Thanks for the helpful info.

Comment: I have two updatepanels with one RadioButton in each of the same Group Name  and with UpdateMode="Always" I solved my problem. Thank you Men